# Import HTML page in .NET

Tags: asp.net

The following code imports an HTML page (which simply holds one table) into my .ASP page. This works great, but I now am converting into .NET and am having obstacles.

```
<% Response.Write(getFilesContent("table.htm")) %>
```

This code does not work in .NET, and I read that this method is not recommended or widely used? Are there any thoughts, advice, or solutions about this?

I simply want to import this HTML page to read in a content box within my .NET page. In essence, the .NET page is hosting the HTML table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

To get you started, take a look at the System.Net.WebClient class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

In particular, the "DownloadXXX" methods.

Comment: Thanks, I will took look at that. I'm new to ASP, so I'm still trying to wrap my head around a lot. I also found another option here: http://webdesign.about.com/od/ssi/a/aa052002a.htm

Comment: I recommend not using the DownloadXXX method at work, that should be saved for use only at home.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the table in an asp.net user control

A asp.net custom user control can act like an include that encapsulates asp.net 
markup.

here is a tutorial:
http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/progaspdotnet_14/index1.html

After you create the control add a reference

```
<%@Register tagprefix="uc" Tagname="html" src="custom_html.ascx" %>
```

then just a the control markup (in this case `<uc:html runat="server"/>`)

It would be cool the create a control the reads an html file by adding a `src` property

Comment: What is a user control? An example? I'm new to ASP and am still learning the foundation of it all. I will look up this terminology though however. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth J for your reference using controls. Unfortunately, the table I am trying to pull from is an existing aspx page. I am pulling this web page to integrate into a mobile site. This custom control would require that I have two pages, and I want to avoid this because I only want to update the table once for both sites in maintenance. However, this was an excellent tutorial, and I could see its value for future projects, so thank you! :)

Comment: You can add any logic of a aspx page to a user control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<% Response.Write(New StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/table.htm")).ReadToEnd()) %>
```

Comment: Breno, how does StreamReader get defined? What is that process read like?

Comment: StreamReader is a .NET Framework class defined into System.IO namespace. It needs a physical path to file, and with ReadToEnd, it returns all data on this file, if it exists.